# How to validate a formatSpec string in MATLAB?

Tags: regex, string, matlab, validation, printf

Many of the functions in MATLAB (and also other language that have a c-derived `scanf`/`printf`) used for writing or reading strings (to name a few: `sscanf`, `sprintf`, `textscan`) rely on the user supplying a valid `formatSpec` string which tells the function the structure of the string-to-build or the string-to-parse. I'm looking for a way to validate such a `formatSpec` string before using it **in a call to [`sprintf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html)**.

In the case of `sprintf`, the structure of `formatSpec` is described [in the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html#btf_bfy-3) and is as follows:

[image: MATLAB's sprintf formatSpec]

Specifically I'd like to point out two aspects of `formatSpec`:

> - (✓) A formatting operator starts with a percent sign, `%`, and ends with a conversion character.
> - (x) `formatSpec` can also include additional text before a percent sign, `%`, or after a conversion character.

**The solution I was thinking about** involves using a regular expression to test the passed-in string. What I have so far is an expression that seems to be able to match everything between the initial `%` and the *conversion character*, but **not** the "additional text" that may appear.

```
(%{1}(\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]*(\d+|\*)?(\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+
```

I wanted to also add the ability to capture "any printable text characters besides `%`, `'` and `\`, unless these characters appear exactly twice". This needs to be captured both before the initial `%` and after the *conversion character*.

- *any printable character*: `[ -~]`
- *besides `%`, `'` and `\`*: `(?![\\%'])`
- *these characters appear exactly twice*: `( §§§§ |'{2}|\\{2}|%{2})` (§ = placeholder)

I am having a problem with the "*unless*", that is, getting the negative look-ahead to discard single occurrences but allow double occurrences of the specified characters.

#### I have two questions:

1. Is there a better way to validate `formatSpec` strings (i.e. w/o regex, or using a better one)?
2. How do I fix my regex so that it works as described?

---

Disambiguation note: in the case of a `formatSpec` string that has "free text" on both sides of *formatting operators*, the text should be considered a part of the **next** *formatting operator*, *unless* there are none left. Below is an example of how a `formatSpec` string should be `split` using the regex (where `|` is the first char of each match):

```
Color %s, number1 %d, number2 %05d, hex %#x, float %5.2f, unsigned value %u.
|       |           |             |        |            |                   |
```

Comment: Have you considered wrapping `sprintf` call into `try`-`catch` block and checking for errors?

Comment: @nirvana-msu Yes I have.. Using `try`/`catch` instead of `if` may be considered an anti-pattern seeing how "[exception handling tends to be an expensive way to handle flow control](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/107727/146757)", so I try to avoid it when possible. I agree that in this specific case, the time saved with going for `try`/`catch` may outweigh the effort to build a correct regex.

Comment: @nirvana-msu I'm afraid this doesn't work. Apparently `sprintf` doesn't fail when `formatSpec` is "slightly invalid" (meaning it works as long as it's a non-empty character vector) even when other inputs are missing or there are too many of them... The second output of `sprintf` _sometimes_ has something to say though. Tested this on MATLAB 2016a.

Answer (score 2):

I've spent a bit of time on this, and I think I'm close, so I'll write up my current progress in an answer. I'm fairly certain it could still be improved.

First, the code, using [the nice example string by Ro Yo Mi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38171408/5067311):

```
% valid input
sample_good = 'Color %s, we are looking for %%02droids %% number1 %d, number2 %05d, hex %#x, float %5.2f, unsigned value %u.';
% invalid input: "%02 droids" has a single percent sign which is not part of an operator
sample_bad = 'Color %s, we are looking for %02 droids %% number1 %d, number2 %05d, hex %#x, float %5.2f, unsigned value %u.';

group_from = '(';
group_to = ')';
printable = '([ -$&-\[\]-~]|%%|\\\\)*';
atomic_op = '(?<!%)%(\d+\$)?[ +#-]*(\d+|\*)?(\.\d*)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]';

% pattern for full validation
full_patt = ['^' group_from printable atomic_op group_to '*' printable '$'];
% pattern for splitting valid strings
part_patt = [printable atomic_op];

% examples
matches_full_bad = regexp(sample_bad,full_patt);            % no match
matches_full_good = regexp(sample_good,full_patt);          % match
matches_parts_good = regexp(sample_good,part_patt,'match'); % sliced matches
```

The first example string is valid, the second is broken due to  `%02 droids` being part of the string. I defined a few auxiliary patterns; note that most of these have groups in them already. The `printable` pattern uses everything ASCII except `%` and `\`, plus `%%` and `\\`. Note that in order to match a double backslash, we need four backshlashes (two escaped backslashes) in the search expression.

What I call `atomic_op` is a pattern that matches format operators starting with a percent sign and ending with a conversion character. It uses negative lookbehind to avoid matching fake format operators starting with `%%`. I took some shortcuts due to laziness (such as `te` being valid in my version). It should be quite functional for not-too-evil inputs.

The most important parts are `full_patt` and `part_patt`. The former tries to match a full format spec, in order to determine if it's valid. Unfortunately, in case of nested groups MATLAB only stores tokens for the *outermost* level; in our case this would not be useful. This is where `part_patt` comes into play: it only matches "printable_string format_operator". Used together with `full_patt` it can be used to slice up your full string to meaningful contributions. Note that `part_patt` will often match an invalid string too at its locally-valid positions, so the two really have to be used together.

Consider the specific example above:

```
>> matches_full_bad

matches_full_bad =

     []

>> matches_full_good

matches_full_good =

     1

>> matches_parts_good{:}

ans =

Color %s


ans =

, we are looking for %%02droids %% number1 %d


ans =

, number2 %05d


ans =

, hex %#x


ans =

, float %5.2f


ans =

, unsigned value %u
```

Let's analyse the results. The "bad" pattern returns a (falsy) empty vector, while the "good" pattern returns a (truthy) `1` for the full pattern. The partial pattern then returns correctly each relevant subpattern of the input. Note, however, that the final period at the end of the sentence is missing from the result, since we matched blocks of `printable atomic_op`. Since we know that we're working with a valid string, the rest of the string (after the final match) should be assign to either a new match, or to the final one, depending on your preference.

Just for clarity, here's how I imagine this to work:

```
for sample={sample_bad,sample_good},
    if regexp(sample{1},full_patt)
        disp('Match found!');
        matches = regexp(sample,part_patt,'match');
        matches = matches{1};   % strip outermost singleton cell dimension
        for k=1:length(matches)
            fprintf('Format substring #%d: %s\n',k, matches{k});
        end
        %TODO: treat final printable part of the string
    else
        disp('Uh-oh, no match!')
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Description

```regex
((?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%'\\])\2)*(%(\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]?(\d+|\*)?(\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+(?:(?!(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%'\\])\7)*(?:%(?:\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]?(?:\d+|\*)?(?:\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+)(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%'\\])\8)*)?)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

<sub>** To see the image better, simply right click the image and select view in new window</sub>

This regular expression will do the following:

- `(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%'\\])\2)*` will match all printable characters from space to `~`, except `%`, `\`, `'` unless they appear exactly twice
- `(%(\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]?(\d+|\*)?(\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+`  is your expression
- `(?:` starts the non-capture group

  - `(?!(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%'\\])\7)*(?:%(?:\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]?(?:\d+|\*)?(?:\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+)` looks ahead to see if there are more format strings
  - `(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%'\\])\8)*)?` if there weren't more format strings above, then this will capture the remaining printable characters
  - `)` end of the capture group

## Example

**Live Demo**

https://regex101.com/r/sV4eX3/2

**Sample text**

```
Color %s, we are looking for %%02droids %% number1 %d, number2 %05d, hex %#x, float %5.2f, unsigned value %u.
```

**Sample Matches**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [0-8]   `Color %s`
3.  [6-8]   `%s`

MATCH 2
1.  [8-53]  `, we are looking for %%02droids %% number1 %d`
2.  [40-41] `%`
3.  [51-53] `%d`

MATCH 3
1.  [53-67] `, number2 %05d`
3.  [63-67] `%05d`
5.  [65-66] `5`

MATCH 4
1.  [67-76] `, hex %#x`
3.  [73-76] `%#x`

MATCH 5
1.  [76-89] `, float %5.2f`
3.  [84-89] `%5.2f`
5.  [85-86] `5`
6.  [86-88] `.2`

MATCH 6
1.  [89-109]    `, unsigned value %u.`
3.  [106-108]   `%u`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - you have a  very impressive regex going on there! Few questions: **1)** How did you create that nice figure? **2)** Could you perhaps explain why my negative lookahead cannot work and requires what you did? **3)** Did you actually test this with MATLAB (if yes - which version)? The reason I'm asking is because the MATLAB `regexp` function is limited and doesn't support all regex operations that exist in other languages/environments. Moreover, I have tested it myself on Octave and on MATLAB R2016a (it's the same syntax) - it worked in Octave but not in MATLAB.

Comment: This is the code I used for testing in MATLAB: `regexp('%d','((?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%''\\])\2)*(%(\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]?(\d+|\*)?(\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+(?:(?!(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%''\\])\7)*(?:%(?:\d+\$)?[-+\s0#]?(?:\d+|\*)?(?:\.\d+)?[bt]?[diuoxXfeEgGcs]+)+)(?:[ -$&(-[\]-~]|([%''\\])\8)*)?)')`. The result in Octave is `1    9   54   68   77   90` (as expected; 1-based notation), the result in MATLAB is `[]`.

Comment: 1. the image is from https://www.debuggex.com/ 2. I pulled your expression apart and found that I needed to retype the `diuoxXfeEgGcs` section something about your characters wasn't working. 3. no I've not tried this in MatLab, but the expression uses only symbols listed in http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/regular-expressions.html#brchk1t so it should would.

Comment: I took the liberty of turning your image into a link, it can be opened by a mouse click now:) Take a look at the answer's source for what it looks like. I suggest though that you upload all images to Stack Overflow's imgur domain, that way you can avoid link rot. I have my doubts about how long debuggex keeps these images (but I didn't want to change this much on your answer). Using SO's image uploader automatically does the linky syntax for you, which is another advantage:)